# Question about index of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be any group with operation $*$ and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:H]=2$

If $a,b \notin H$ ,why $a*b \in H$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G = H\cup gH$ and $G/H$ is a cyclic group of order $2$ with multiplication $gH\cdot gH = H$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ has index $2$ in $G$, it is normal. Then $G/H \cong C_2$ and so the non-trivial element (to which both $a$ and $b$ correspond) has order $2$ in the quotient, *i.e.* $ab \in H$ within $G$.